# Grabbing redirect request source in WordPress or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am trying to run a Javascript file via conditions based on the request, (A.K.A. the previous URL) that the current page was accessed from. For example, if the user was redirected **to the login page**, logged in, and then **returned to the previous page**, that would trigger the JavaScript (whereas simply visiting the page would not).

Does **WordPress** or **PHP** have a way to check the request source?

### Update:

*WOOOOAAAH, WE'RE HALFWAY THEEERE!*

Based on **user1091949**'s suggestion, I have gone ahead and added code to run my JavaScript file based on the presence of a **cookie**:

```
if ( !isset( $_COOKIE['mmmcookies'] ) ) {
    setcookie( 'mmmcookies', 1, 5 );
}

function media_kit_script() {
    $page_id = get_queried_object_id();
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['mmmcookies'] ) ) {
            if ($page_id === 1947) {
                wp_enqueue_script( 'media-kit-init' );
            }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'media_kit_script' );
```

The script is registered in a previous function, and everything works! Now, here's my next question: I need to implement `setcookie()` based on the fact that the user has come from logging in, i.e.:

```
if ( user_came_from_login() ) {
    if ( !isset( $_COOKIE['mmmcookies'] ) ) {
    setcookie( 'mmmcookies', 1, 5 );
    }
```

And so on. **How would I do this?**

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cookie. The start page:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['iwashere'])) {
    setcookie('iwashere', 1, time()+315360000);
}
```

The page where Javascript is needed if the user came from the page above:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['iwashere'])) {
    echo '<script src="someJavascript.js"></script>';
}
```

Of course, you may need to change the expire time for the cookie.

Comment: In the words of a certain musical friend of mine, WE'RE HALFWAY THEEEERE! The cookie is workin' great. However, how would I set the cookie only on the condition that the user just came from login?

Answer (score 0):

That would be the referer (and it's not very reliable):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Wordpress has it's [own version](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer):

```
wp_get_referer()
```

that accesses `$_REQUEST['_wp_http_referer'])` internally

Comment: I actually gave `HTTP_REFERER` a shot, but like you said, it's far too flimsy. Thanks, though!